# How to check Net::Telnet session is still live in Perl?

Tags: perl, telnet

I have a Perl script to run some commands on remote equipment by Net::Telnet. Sometimes, telnet session would be disconnected by remote side because login timeout or other cause. I want to know how I can check telnet session is still live before send next command? Thanks a lot!

```
my $tc = new Net::Telnet{Host=>$host,Port=>23};
sub checkTelnetLive { ??? }
my @commands=($cmd1,$cmd2,...);
foreach $cmd(@commands) {
    if checkTelnetLive {
        $tc->put($cmd);
        $tc->waitfor('/COMPLD/');
    }
    else {
        die "Remote equipment has disconnected session."
    }

}
```

Comment: **timed_out - time-out indicator** `$boolean = $obj->timed_out;` `$prev = $obj->timed_out($boolean);` _This method indicates if a previous read, write, or open method timed-out. Remember that timing-out is itself an error. To be able to invoke timed_out() after a time-out error, you'd have to change the default error mode to something other than "die". See errmode().
With no argument this method returns 1 if the previous method timed-out. With an argument it sets the indicator. Normally, only internal methods set this indicator._

Answer (score 0):

```
my $tc = new Net::Telnet (Host=> $host, Port=>23, Errmode => 'return' );
```

or you can use `eval`

```
eval {
      my $tc = new Net::Telnet (Host=> $host, Port=>23, Errmode => 'return' );

#. plus other code
};
warn $@ if $@;
```